# Google Sheets: Copy conditional formatting over multiple cells, while referencing other cells relatively

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[image: Two rows]

I want cell F4 to be coloured red if its value is bigger than cel H4

The same for F5 and H5 and so on.

I have tried creating the conditional formula and pasting it in the other cells, but it copies over the EXACT formula. I want the formula to be relative, so that if I copy it from F(n) downwards it matches the relative H(n)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually want to do is highlight all of column F, choose custom formula as your condition and enter this formula in:

`=$F1>$H1`

Note the `$` on the column, but not on the row number - this allows it to be dynamic

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!